# Ionic Photoviewer - how to use?

Tags: ionic2, photoviewer

I am a beginner in Ionic 2 and I would like to know how you use Photoviewer functionnality from Ionic framework. (available here : [official website](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/photo-viewer))

It said :

Usage

```
import { PhotoViewer } from '@ionic-native/photo-viewer';

constructor(private photoViewer: PhotoViewer) { }

...

this.photoViewer.show('https://example.com/path/to/image.jpg');

this.photoViewer.show('https://example.com/path/to/image.jpg', 'My image title', {share: false});
```

But  where do I need to put it ? in a function ? how the function will be called ?

Thank's for all.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function like

```
zoomImage(imageData) {
      this.photoViewer.show(imageData);
  }
```

and call this function on your image click.

```
 <img src="/path/to/image.jpg" (click)="zoomImage('/path/to/image.jpg')"/>
```